# Download PDF files from a FTP and join them

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf

I'm building a web-app where a list of buildings come up, each building has a flyer.pdf storaged on an FTP. I already figured out how to download the PDF but the users need to select each one and join it on a single one.

I already tried using a foreach function but all the dependencies I find to join PDFs require a route rather than a blob, the code below is what I use for a single one, I'm just using a query to pass an array with all the buildings IDs (inmbID).

```
 uploadRouter.route("/downloadPDF").get((req, res) => {
  console.log("TCL: req.params", req.query.InmbIDs)

  req.query.InmbIDs.forEach(inmbID => {
    Ftp.ls(`/${inmbID}/flyerPdf`, (err, res1) => {
      if (!res1[0]) {
        return res.send("No hay nada para bajar");
      } else {
        let check = res1.sort().reverse()[0];

        Ftp.get(`${inmbID}/${fileType}/${check.name}`, (err, socket) => {
          let opts = {};
          if (err) {
            return;
          }

          let data = [];
          socket.on("data", d => {
            data.push(d);
          });

          socket.on("end", hadErr => {
            if (hadErr) {
              console.log("There was an error retrieving the file.");
            }
            data = Buffer.concat(data);
            const ext = check.name.split(".")[1];
            res.writeHead(200, {
              "Content-Type": `.${ext}`,
              "Content-disposition": "attachment; filename=" + `"${check.name}"`,
              "Content-Length": data.length
            });

            res.end( data );
          });

          socket.resume();
        });
      }
    });
  });


});
```

I expect the browser to handle a single PDF file with all the flyer.pdf joined